# Difficulties with variable declaration in Python

Tags: python

I have the following piece of code which I am trying to use to declare multiple variables at the same time:

```
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + ".txt", "r") as myurls:
            myurls2_x_y = myurls.read().replace('\n', '')
```

When i added a `print(myurls2_x_y)` and viewed the log the above code was opening each dynamic file path in sequence, then displaying and cleaning up the strings in the above text files as expected.

However, using this method in something like SAS (which is my main language) I was expecting  each of the variable values to be retained as they have different names, i.e. i would expect to have variables `myurls2_1_1`, `myurls2_1_2`, `myurls2_1_3` etc all declared.

The idea then is to pass them through a URL = declaration within some `concurrent.futures` Python code that I have so that I can submit multiple URLS at once.

All that works fine apart from when the script comes to resolve the variables dynamically generated it gets to the first one, `myurls2_1_1` and says that it isn't defined when it is.

Any ideas why that might be?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using [lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)? You could use `myurls2[x][y]` with nested lists.

Comment: im a bit sketchy around lists and dictionaries at the minute as to how to code them. actually one thing i hadn't thought of is that I will need to define this variables globally I think.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a dictionary using an `x,y` tuple as the key:

```
myurls = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):
        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Here's a example that I can run without your files to demonstrate lookup:

```
myurls = {}

TEMPLATE = r'C:\Python33\NASDAQ Stock Strings\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt'

def content(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().replace('\n', '')

for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):
        #myurls[x,y] = content(TEMPLATE.format(x,y))
        myurls[x,y] = TEMPLATE.format(x,y)

print(myurls[1,5])
```

Output:

```
C:\Python33\NASDAQ Stock Strings\NASDAQ_Config_File_1_5.txt
```

Comment: Ok thanks. What is most likely to resolve this issue? Using a dictionary or globally declaring the variables? Or do I need to do both?

Comment: Your issue is assuming how Python works.  Python is not SAS. Defining `myurls2_x_y` *only* defines `myurls2_x_y` as a variable.  Python will not magically create `myurls2_1_1`, etc. for you.  Use dictionaries or lists instead and access them with `myurls[x,y]` (for dict) or `myurls[x][y]` (for lists).

Comment: Using the exact syntax in your answer i got the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\test2.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}".format(x,y),"r") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_1_1'

Comment: But it is definitely there.

Comment: I left out the `.txt`.  Fixing.  I don't have your files so the code was untested.

Comment: sorry, yes...just noticed that after i responded.